# Why describe code evaluated earlier than beforeAll?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have met strange behaviour for me in the jest. I know that jest works the next way:

1. Execute each describe
2. Start For each `describe`
3. register all `beforeAll`, `beforeEach`, `it`
4. execute all `beforeAll`
5. execute all `it`, but before each `it` execute all registered `beforeEach`
6. go to next `describe`
7. end for each `describe`

So with that in mind I meet strange behaviour.

```
describe('timer clicks', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        // some setup
                global.Date = class extends Date {
            constructor(year?: number, month?: number, day?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number) {
                hours == null
                    ? super(now)
                    : super(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, ms || 0);
            }
        } as any;
    });
    describe('Vitals timer clicked', () => {
        describe('Case 1', () => {
            describe('Case 1.1', () => {
                beforeAll(() => {
                     (sut()).vitalsTimerClicked(); // Here the Date object hasn't been mocked
                })
            })

            describe('Case 1.2', () => {
                 beforeAll(() => {
                    (sut()).vitalsTimerClicked(); // Here the Date object has been mocked
                 });
            });
});

// that is how testEventLogRecordWrapper looks
function testEventLogRecordWrapper() {
        return () => {
             beforeAll(() => {});
             it('some field', () => expect);
        }
}
```

As far as I know, when calling `vitalsTimerClicked` on the deepest `beforeAll`, the Date object should be already mocked, however for some reason it doesn't work for `Case 1.1`, but works for `Case 1.2`. Why?

Comment: You should explicit what makes you think the date object is mocked or not. I would rather believe it is mocked in 1.1 (you should add some console.log in beforeAll), and it appears not to for some reason (only you know) and appears mocked in 1.2 because mocked(mocked(Date)) ~= Date

Comment: I'd expect sync beforeAll to be executed in this order but this shouldn't be relied on as they are guaranteed to be executed *before tests* in parallel, their relationship is unimportant. In case the order is important, do some function composition to make sure they are called in the order you expect. The use of beforeAll to mock a global is unjustified. This can be done on top level, it's either mocked or not. For test-specific mocks use beforeEach instead.

Comment: @grodzi put in the right direction, I have ensured that date has been mocked for all the cases. I have no idea what happened, but possibly some other issue with running the code. Finaly, I decided to leave that test to the last and write other unit tests, during this I have made some changes in code and tests and problem disappear, even I don't know what cause.